# Creating dictionary from numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, numpy

I have an numpy array and I want to create a dictionary from the array.

More specifically I want a dictionary that has keys that correspond to the row, so key 1 should be the sum of row 1.

s1 is my array and I know how to get the sum of the row but doing `numpy.sum(s1[i])`, where i is the row.

I was thinking of creating a loop where I can compute the sum of the row and then add it to a dictionary but I am new to programming so I am not sure how to do this or if it is possible.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

**EDIT**

I created the key values with the range function.
Then zipped the keys and the array.

```
mydict = dict(zip(keys, s1))
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'd do something similar in spirit to your `dict(zip(keys, s1))`, with two minor changes.

First, we can use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate), and second, we can call the [`sum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sum.html) method of `ndarray`s.  Example:

```
>>> arr = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
>>> arr
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
>>> arr.sum(axis=1)
array([ 3, 12, 21])
>>> dict(enumerate(arr.sum(axis=1)))
{0: 3, 1: 12, 2: 21}
```